# Paypal Mass payment Fee Charge

Tags: paypal, masspay

It is unclear how much paypal charges when we do mass payment from our application.Would anybody let me know the details.

currently i found "For Mass Payments to recipients within the U.S., the fee is 2% of total up to $1 per payment. For Mass Payments to recipients outside the U.S.,the fee is 2% of total up to a maximum of $20.00 USD per payment, or the foreign currency equivalent of $20.00 USD."
information in paypal site.

what if i send 6000 $ to one/two user?Any answers and suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Paypal is very poor in documentation and do not have intuitive guide.

Thanks.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about PayPal billing rates, not programming.

Answer (score 1):

For example in the case of your 6000 dollar transaction.   If it is a Domestic transaction you would be charged $1 fee for that transaction and if it was international it would be $20.

The breakdown is basically as the information you provide.   Each transaction is charge to either the percentage or the fixed amount, whichever is lower.   This fee is charged for each payment in your request.   So if domestic a 50 transaction request would be a maximium of $50 or $1 per transaction.   While internationally this would be $1000 for the same 50 transactions.

Comment: When checking through paypals transaction meter it is always 2% for national and international transaction.Different links have contradicting tax structure.

general taxing structure                                                        1.https://cms.paypal.com/ch/cgi-bin/marketingweb?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=ua/FeesPolicy_full&locale.x=en_US                    2.https://www.paypal.com/np/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_batch-payment-overview-outside